# Aggregate Exception: Firebase Cannot Find Image Specified

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I've been programming an AR app in Unity, and I just transitioned over to ARCore since I've started using Firebase, and both are Google products. I am trying to store images on Firebase and pull them on runtime to an AugmentedImageDatabase, but for some reason, Firebase always gives me a FileNotFound exception when I try to download the images.

I am referencing the storage service and bucket via

```
storageService = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
storageRef = storageService.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://avira-cc267.appspot.com"); //Name changed since permissions are temporarily open to public
```

And I attempt to download them via

```
foreach (Transform obj in imageTargets)
        {
            Firebase.Storage.StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.Child("ImageTargets/" + obj.gameObject.name + ".jpg");
            const long maxAllowedSize = 1024 * 1024; //1mb
            imageRef.GetBytesAsync(maxAllowedSize).ContinueWith((Task<byte[]> task) =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString()); //This is where the error is called.
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] fileContents = task.Result;
                    callbacks.Enqueue(() => {
                        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2); //size doesnt matter, it gets changed
                        tex.LoadImage(fileContents);
                        config.AugmentedImageDatabase.AddImage(obj.gameObject.name, new AugmentedImageSrc(tex), 1f);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the error in question

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Firebase.Storage.StorageException: Not Found.  Could not get object  Http Code: 404
```

I have checked all the paths I am referencing, and they are all typo-free and named properly. The rules in Firebase are set to public

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

So these should not be giving me a problem. For some reason, the app cannot find the instance of the image I am referencing even though the path is the same as it appears in Firebase. Does anyone know why I cannot download my images? Am I referencing the path wrong somewhere?

EDIT: Added picture to prove my error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That error will happen when the object you're requesting doesn't exist in your storage bucket.  It has nothing to do with your security rules.

We can't see exactly what you're trying to access, since you have information hidden behind variable we can't see:

```
storageRef.Child("ImageTargets/" + obj.gameObject.name + ".jpg");
```

You will have to make sure that object actually exists in the bucket with the name you're passing.  Whatever it is you're passing now, it's just not there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I thought I clarified all this in the question. I said specifically that I debugged the path it was sending to the storage reference, and it's correct. The path I am sending is gs://avira-cc267.appspot.com/ImageTargets/ImageName.jpg. Firebase default bucket is gs://avira-cc267.appspot.com, images are in a folder called ImageTargets, titles are all correct for each image I am passing. There is no double '/' or missing '/' in my path. Although the only thing that throws a FileNotFound is an incorrect path or missing file to my knowledge, that is not the problem.

Comment: Well, we can't really see all that.  We can't see the path of the reference (you need to log it and copy it into the question, or perhaps hard code it).  We also can't see that the file exists in the bucket (you need to take a screenshot and prove it).

Comment: If your image name is "ImageName.jpg", as you say, I don't see it in there.

Comment: It's obviously not, that's a placeholder. I am here because I've tried everything, any simple solution is not going to work. Don't mention the fact that my bucket is named aivra instead of avira in my post either, like previously mentioned, the db is public and I didn't want random people finding this post and modifying it, but I don't care any more. I just need help.

Comment: If we can't see that the exact name that you're requesting is the same as what's in the bucket, there's nothing we can do.  The value of `obj.gameObject.name` is probably not what you expect, and we can't see what it is.  You are going to have to debug your code.